# Bootstrap foreach loop

Tags: html, loops, foreach, dwoo

I have somethink like this.

```
<div id="main_categories" class="row" data-equalizer>
    {foreach key=row item=category from=$results}   
    <div class="product col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail clearfix text-center">
            <div class="image" data-equalizer-watch="image">{$category.photo}</div>
            <div class="caption" data-equalizer-watch="caption">
              <h3 class="name">{$category.name}</h3>
              {if $category.subcategories}
              <p class="hidden-xs">
                  {foreach key=row item=category_subcategories from=$category.subcategories} 
                      <span class="subcategory">{$category_subcategories.name}</span>
                  {/foreach}
              </p>
              {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
{/foreach}

</div>
```

Is there any chance that the 3th and 4th or second and 3th photos appear in different ways not col-lg-3 but col-lg-6?

Comment: Please include the name of your template language in the question and add its tag (if available). This does not seem like standard HTML functionality.

Comment: I use https://www.soteshop.com/. It is part of code which let me show categories with pictures on the home page

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging I've found that SoteShop runs on PHP, and out of the couple most popular template languages this looks the most similar to [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/).

Looking through the documentation and piecing together the syntax leads me to believe that the following should work:

```
<div id="main_categories" class="row" data-equalizer>
    {foreach key=row item=category from=$results}
    {* 3rd and 4th elements (index 2 and 3) *}
    {if $.foreach.default.index == 2 || $.foreach.default.index == 3}
        {assign 6 lgcol}
    {else}
        {assign 3 lgcol}
    {/if}
    <div class="product col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-{$lgcol}">
        <div class="thumbnail clearfix text-center">
            <div class="image" data-equalizer-watch="image">{$category.photo}</div>
            <div class="caption" data-equalizer-watch="caption">
              <h3 class="name">{$category.name}</h3>
              {if $category.subcategories}
              <p class="hidden-xs">
                  {foreach key=row item=category_subcategories from=$category.subcategories} 
                      <span class="subcategory">{$category_subcategories.name}</span>
                  {/foreach}
              </p>
              {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    {/foreach}
</div>
```